# VBA : key-pair dictionary

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary, key-value

I go with Late binding as i got error using Early binding.
Instead of showing the 3 activesheet name, the output is like this

> Key:  Value:

Never tried this before. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

```
Sub LoopKeys()

Dim key As Variant
Dim country As Variant

country = Array("Kentucky", "California", "Ohio")

dic.Add "Kentucky", "Alicia"
dic.Add "California", "Ken"
dic.Add "Ohio", "Benjamin"

For sheet = LBound(country) To UBound(country)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(country(sheet)).Activate

    If ActiveSheet.Name = " & key & " Then
        Debug.Print "Key: " & key & " Value: " & dic(key)
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Scripting.Dictionary object you need to loop through the `Keys` collection:

```
Dim key As Variant
For Each key In dic.Keys
    Debug.Print "Key: " & key & " Value: " & dic(key)
Next key
```

**Update 1:**

---

```
Sub LoopKeys()
    Dim dic As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dic = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim s As Worksheet
    For Each s In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        dic.Add key:=CStr(s.Index), Item:=s.Name
    Next s

    Dim key As Variant
    For Each key In dic.Keys
        Debug.Print "Key: " & key & " Value: " & dic(key)
    Next key

    Set dic = Nothing
End Sub

'Key: 1 Value: Sheet1
'Key: 2 Value: Sheet2
'Key: 3 Value: Sheet3
```

**Update 2:**

---

```
Sub LoopKeys()
    Dim dic As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dic = New Scripting.Dictionary

    With dic
        .Add key:="Kentucky", Item:="Alicia"
        .Add key:="California", Item:="Ken"
        .Add key:="Ohio", Item:="Benjamin"
    End With

    Dim key As Variant
    For Each key In dic.Keys
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(key).Activate
        Debug.Print "Key: " & key & " Value: " & dic(key)
    Next key

    Set dic = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: is there anyway that can be applied to my situation ? i wanna get activesheet name.
or this function actually wont fits ?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. Loop through worksheets?

Comment: hmm .. I'm trying to activate the sheet (key) then have it to show me the value? there are more than 3 sheets in my workbook. but I only want those three. So by looping through the sheets and activate them one at a time, I supposed I would have respective value. lets say when it's at Kentucky sheet, I wanna see Alicia as value ?

Comment: @Santa See update. You can fill the dictionary by looping through sheets (update 1) and select each sheet by its name (update 2).